# (spring-boot) http to https redirect, 405 method not allow message

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Spring boot and http to https redirect using by elastic beanstalk in AWS.
so I request http then redirect https, and re-request by https protocol...
in https, everything is ok,
but in http, get method(in controller) is ok, but post method isn't ok...
`{
    "timestamp": 1508137623531,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/api/test"
}`

My controller code
`@PostMapping(value = "/test")
public String test(@RequestBody String name) {
    return "hello, " + name;
}`

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108498/redirect-post-method-http-https-http-status-405-spring-boot), but it doesn't help to me...

How can I fix it...?

Answer (score 1):

Standby counsel

It is web server(nginx, apache, etc.)'s trouble not spring boot.
I use 301 redirect, but 301 is changed from post to get.
so, I have to use 308 instead of 301.
308 isn't allowed changed from post to get,
but elastic beanstalk use nginx v1.12.1
and 1.12.1 doesn't support 308, [1.13.0 support 308](https://nginx.org/en/CHANGES)

so I should update nginx...

Comment: I have run into the same issue with the POST call. Were you able to solve the it by updating nginx? Not sure if it's scalable though, since nginx 1.13.x is on mainline and Amazon seems to only support stable channel with 1.12.x with Beanstalk.

Using `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` didn't help me either.

Comment: @testphreak I did not update because it did not seem to work properly,
so I use 307 Temporary Redirect

Comment: if I use 307, both http and https based POST calls are allowed. My expectation is if you make a POST API call using HTTP, it will redirect to HTTPS. Is that a wrong expectation?

In the /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf, I added

`
......
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
        set $redirect 1;
      }
      if ($redirect = 1) {
        return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
......
`
After this I restarted NGINX on the instance. Didn't work for me.